# Vectors, How to measure total force and direction.

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-physics

I am currently looking for some math help that I am quite struggling with. The problem is:

> (Vectors) A fisherman use his pole and line to pull a fish out of the
>   water. The line exerts a force on the fish that is $9.4 N$ in the
>   horizontal direction, and $15.4 N$ in the vertical direction. What is
>   the size of the total force, and its direction(measured from
>   horizontal)?

I'm assuming I would proceed to use the pythagorean theorem to solve the total force, but how would I find the direction? I'm aware of it would be one of the Sine, Cosine, or Tangents, but I am not sure how to identify which one to use it to calculate it.

$\sqrt{9.4^2 + 15.4^2} = 18.04217$ which is the total force.

Comment: It depends how you define total force(by what model?)... This is a homework engingeering physics problem, not a mathematical physics question.

Comment: It is mathematics used in physics; I wasn't 100% sure where to post it exactly. I can provide a screenshot if desired.

Comment: In class, you are "given", all the forces that you should consider, represent them as vectors, and then add them up by the paralelogram rule. The size is the length of the total force vector, which is the distance between the endpoints of the vector. Regarding the direction, suppose the resultant vector is the hypothenuse of a right angled triangle, what is the angle between the lower side of the triangle and the hypothenuse?(you have the length of the sides, what's the definition of the cosine?)

Comment: Draw a picture. The angle and how to compute it will be clear.

Comment: agreed the "total force", once added the square root ($18.04 N$ is correct). Angle: $\tan^{-1}(15.4/9.4)$...?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, but generally 99% of the time I have found out that you use the tan ratio to solve these types of problems in terms of angle.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 known sides of a right triangle. You can use the Pythagorean theorem to discover the other side. Obviously, because there are more than 1 known sides and the angle is unknown, you wouldn't use any trigonometric ratio. You need to apply an inverse trigonometric function.